# Is it safer to download a file from the internet and open it versus opening a DVD?

Tags: network, malware, virus

Recently I was in the hospital and I brought the results of all test that were done by doctors with me on a DVD to avoid printing 100 pages. I wanted the doctor in the hospital to see it, but she refused, saying that she could not put a DVD in her DVD-drive due to viruses. But she could get the file via internet.

Is it safer to download a file from the internet and open it versus opening a DVD?

Answer (score 1):

Information security policies in corporations and other businesses are strict when it comes to removable media. There is the risk of abuse from someone copying malicious data to and from the removable media, both knowingly and unknowingly, the same risks will also apply with Internet media, let's take a look at the Pros and Cons of both Network Level Traffic Filtering and Local Scanning.

**Pros/Cons of Network Level Traffic Filtering:**

- One index of virus definitions to keep updated
- Scanning is in real time
- All clients on the network are protected, not just the ones that the virus definitions index is updated on.
- The benefits won't extend to scanning USBs, DVDs, etc

**Pros/Cons of Local Scanning:**

- One index of virus definitions per device to keep updated, whileas this can be mostly automated, there are various risks including tampering, a device might not have the latest update downloaded yet, etc so there are potential problems with operating this at scale so this shouldn't be the first line of defense on large networks.
- The benefits are extended to scanning USBs, DVDs, etc making sure that all media is scanned against the index.
- Only clients with the scanning installed are safe.

It's safe to say that while both formats of media have their own sets of risks, and while each form of filtering/scanning has it's own pros and cons, the filtering of network traffic can be centralized while removable media cannot be easily centralized. So to summarize getting a file from the Internet isn't really safer, but from the network administration perspective, it's a lot easier for them to manage and I understand why such a policy is in place.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the computer gets all its traffic through a proxy server that performs virus scanning.  That's the only condition by which I'd say that there'd be any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say. Both involve risks.

I would guess that the hospital uses a proxy that does virus scanning. For a big organisation, it is much easier to do the virus scanning of all network traffic on one proxy instead of doing it locally on hundreds or possibly thousands of machines. If that is the case, just popping in a DVD might "circumvent" some of the security.

Or the doctor has just learnt the rule "don't insert unknown removable media". That is not at all a bad rule - you should not plug in the lost USB you find in the corridor. But when the alternative is to download files from the internet it is not obvious that is better.